# How to compare multiple schedule and attendance on the same day

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize for the trivial question, spent many hours Googling to the answer for this question.Please help..
I have a table schedule for student's schedule and table attendance for student's attendance. What I want is to compare student's schedule to his attendance.

table schedule

```
ID | stud_id | day   | timein  | timeout | schedule_hour |
1  | 8888    | Monday| 08:00AM | 09:00AM |   1           |
2  | 8888    | Monday| 10:00AM | 12:00PM |   2           |
3  | 8888    | Monday| 01:00PM | 03:00PM |   2           |
4  | 8888    |Tuesday| 07:00AM | 09:00AM |   2           |  
5  | 8888    |Tuesday| 03:00PM | 04:00PM |   1           |
6  | 8888    |Tuesday| 06:00PM | 08:00PM |   2           |
```

table attendance

```
ID |  stud_id | day   | timein  | timeout |  hour |
 1  | 8888    | Monday| 07:55AM | 09:10AM |1.15   |
 2  | 8888    | Monday| 09:51AM | 12:03PM |2.12   |
 3  | 8888    | Monday| 12:50PM | 03:05PM |2.15   |
 4  | 8888    |Tuesday| 06:53AM | 09:15AM |2.22   | 
 5  | 8888    |Tuesday| 02:50PM | 04:06PM |1.16   |
 6  | 8888    |Tuesday| 05:52PM | 08:09PM |2.17   |
 7  | 8888    |Tuesday| 09:52PM | 10:09PM |1.17   |
```

php code is given below:-

```
<?php
$query=$conn->query("SELECT *
FROM student a,attendance d,schedule e
WHERE a.student_id = d.student_id
AND d.student_id = e.student_id
AND a.student_id = $get_id")or die(mysql_error());
$totalhour = 0;
$totalitems = 0;

function hourandmin($time1){
$hour = 0;
$minute = 0;
while($time1 > 1.0){
$hour = $hour + 1;
$time1 = $time1 - 1;
}

if($time1 < 1.0){
$minute = $time1 * 60;
}

$time1 = round($hour).".".round($minute)."";
return $time1;
}

while($row = $query->fetch()){

$date = strtotime($row['login']);
$date2 = strtotime($row['logout']);
$hour = ($date2 - $date) / (60*60);
if ($hour < 0){
$hour = 0;
}
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['student_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['day']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['timein']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['timeout']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo  hourandmin((($hour))); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $schedule_hour; ?></td>





                                </tr>
                                    <?php  } ?>
```

I have no idea how to output the schedule hour
so for example on attendance table row 7 he timed in but because he doesn't have the schedule for that time the output is overtime

```
ID | stud_id | day   | timein  | timeout | hour |schedule_hour
1  | 8888    | Monday| 07:55AM | 09:10AM |  1.15| 1
2  | 8888    | Monday| 09:51AM | 12:03PM |  2.12| 2
3  | 8888    | Monday| 12:50PM | 03:05PM |  2.15| 2
4  | 8888    |Tuesday| 06:53AM | 09:15AM |  2.22| 2
5  | 8888    |Tuesday| 02:50PM | 04:06PM |  1.16| 1
6  | 8888    |Tuesday| 05:52PM | 08:09PM |  2.17| 2 
7  | 8888    |Tuesday| 09:52PM | 10:09PM |  1.17| overtime
```

Comment: Please explain your problem more precisely

Comment: hi @Mawcel , I wanted to compare the attendance table and schedule table so I can display the schedule hours, sorry not really good in english..

Comment: how did this even output "overtime" when there's no "overtime" string used anywhere in your code?

Comment: and by comparison, do you mean compare each schedule and attendance of the same ids? because if you do, you need to use LEFT INNER JOIN in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT tatt.stud_id, tatt.day, tatt.timein, tatt.timeout, tatt.hour,tsched.schedule_hour FROM table_attendance tatt INNER JOIN table_schedule tsched ON tsched.stud_id = tatt.stud_id AND tsched.day = tatt.day AND tatt.timein <= tsched.timein AND tatt.timeout > tsched.timeout;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$query=$conn->
query("
select a.student_id, d.timein, d.timeout, e.timein, e.timeout 
from student a
inner join attendance d on a.student_id = d.student_id
inner join schedule e on a.student_id = e.student_id
where a.student_id = $get_id
")or die(mysql_error());
$totalhour = 0;
$totalitems = 0;

function hourandmin($time1){
$hour = 0;
$minute = 0;
while($time1 > 1.0){
$hour = $hour + 1;
$time1 = $time1 - 1;
}

if($time1 < 1.0){
$minute = $time1 * 60;
}

$time1 = round($hour).".".round($minute)."";
return $time1;
}

while($row = $query->fetch()){

$date = strtotime($row['d.login']);
$date2 = strtotime($row['d.logout']);

$hour = ($date2 - $date) / (60*60);
if ($hour < 0){
$hour = 0;
}

function schedule($date, $date2){
$date3 = strtotime($row['e.timein']);
$date4 = strtotime($row['e.timeout']);
if $date1 < $date3 && $date2 > $date4 {
$schedule_hour = $date4 - $date3;
else {
$schedule_hour = round($hour);
}

}

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['student_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['day']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['timein']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['timeout']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo  hourandmin((($hour))); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $schedule_hour; ?></td>
```